# Number only visible slides using master slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want hidden slides in my presentation to be skipped in the slide numbering. I do, however, have a master slide that has text boxes as the footer and slide number, and this number is what I need to be updated when slides are hidden/unhidden. This is a picture of the footer in the master slide:

[image]

I already tried the solution posted here but it does not work. 
[VBA : Number the slide if they are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266264/vba-number-the-slide-if-they-are-visible/35277025#35277025)
I think it's because of the master slide. This is the error I get:

```
Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)':
HeaderFooter (unkown member) : Invalid request.
```

And when debugging it it highlights this line of code as the problem:

```
diapo.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = CStr(x)
```

Comment: From your post, it sounds like you are using text boxes for the slide number instead of the standard slide number placeholder. Is that true? If so, why?

Comment: Would that help?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362448/how-not-to-count-page-numbers-for-hidden-slides-in-ppt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362448/how-not-to-count-page-numbers-for-hidden-slides-in-ppt)

Comment: Corporate standars, I need to keep the footer that way.